# Simple counting through loop php?

Tags: php, variables, loops

I've got a simple problem that I'm not quite sure how to get around using a loop to grab php variables and add them together

Let's say I've got this loop

```
$total = 0;
while ( $foo ='bar' );
    $amount = meta($row, 'amount');
endwhile;

$total = 'NEW AMOUNT';
```

my question is, how do I add amounts (anywhere from 1 to 200) together to create the bottom `$total`? the amount of objects from `while ( $foo ='bar');` is ever growing and can be 2 total objects, or 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to `$total` and change the `;` in front of the `while` with `:` to start that `while`:

```
$total = 0;
while ( $foo = 'bar' ):
    $total += meta($row, 'amount'); // assuming `meta()` is one of your functions that extract `amount` from someplace ..
endwhile;

echo $total;
```

Comment: wonderful! Works great :) - PS yes, `meta()` is one of my functions :). Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$total = 0;
while ( $foo ='bar' )
{
    $amount = meta($row, 'amount');
    $total = $total + $amount;
}
```

Something like this?
If both `$total` and `$amount` are integers you can just add them together.

Also I assume `meta()` is a method which calculates an amount and returns it?

Notice how I changed the while loop (added braces), after the closing brace you should have your `$total` variable with the total amount in it.